# VBA Excel 2010 format textbox value as currecy

Tags: excel, vba

I need to format three text box values as currency.  The initial values, read from a spreadsheet, are already formatted as currency in the sheet, however, I am having trouble formatting the text box properly.  If the value is not a whole number, the box will display 10.5.0 instead of 10.50.

here is my project
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183889559/concession.xlsm

and here is the code containing the formatting argument

```
'enter user ID
Public Sub mavid_btn_Click()
mavID = Me.id_txt.Text 'get user id number entered
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Sheets("TEAM ROSTER").Activate 'activate sheet with roster
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" 'while cell is not blank
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = mavID Then 'if user input matches ID in team roster
        name = Cells(i, 2).Value 'get cell value for name
        Me.name_txt.Text = name 'populate name to name text box
        balance = Cells(i, 3).Value 'get cell value for balance
        Me.bal_txt.Text = VAL(balance) 'populate balance to balance text box
        Me.bal_txt.Text = Format(Me.bal_txt.Text, "##.##")'  
        Dim history() As String
        history = Split(Cells(i, 4).Value, ", ") 'split purchase history values in column D into array
        Dim index As Variant
        For Each index In history 'populate array to listbox
            With Me.history_lbx
                .AddItem index
            End With
        Next index
        total = 0 'set total equal to 0 to start
        payment = 0 'set payment equal to 0 to start
        Me.total_txt.Text = VAL(total) 'set total to value
        Me.pay_txt.Text = VAL(payment) 'set payment to value
        balance = VAL(balance) ' set value
        total = VAL(total) 'set total to value
        payment = VAL(payment) 'set payment to value

        Me.total_txt.Font.name = "Arial" 'text box formatting to match rest of form
        Me.total_txt.Font.Size = 14
        Me.pay_txt.Font.name = "Arial"
        Me.pay_txt.Font.Size = 14
        Exit Do
    Else
        i = i + 1 'else move to next cell in column A
    End If
Loop
If balance < 0 Then 'formatting for balance based on sign (+ or -)
    Me.bal_txt.ForeColor = vbRed
Else
    Me.bal_txt.ForeColor = vbBlack
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: the link doesn't work. if you want a code review use: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Please try to reduce your problem to a smaller set and fix the link.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I have changed my question and fixed the link.

Comment: I'm looking at this, but am curious.. in subroutine 'done_btn_Click()' you have line 'histReturn = histReturn & j' with histReturn being an array.  Don't you get a compile error?  What are you trying to do with that? AND check your loop!

Comment: wayne, I am getting a compile error, but I am only posting one issue at a time.  with the histReturn array, i was attempting to pass the listbox items to an array, then use the array to update a cell value.  Column D contains the purchase history of each user with a comma delimiter.

Comment: do you still need help with this, or is it good?

Comment: Yes, sorry. the payment and total populate with a .00, which is fine.  When I use the format on the balance, i enter an id number and the balance does not show until i use the add to balance button.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183889559/concession.xlsm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, and a value of $10.50. the Balance field displays as "$10.5" not "10.5.0" as you mentioned. The solution to get the proper decimal places shown is to change the following line

```
Me.bal_txt.Text = Format(Me.bal_txt.Text, "##.##")
```

to

```
Me.bal_txt.Text = Format(Me.bal_txt.Text, "##.00")
```

Also, please check for compile errors since you reference an Array improperly.

Comment: for some reason, the balance textbox is not showing the balance until after the pay button is clicked

Comment: Please clarify. When you enter the ID and click 'Enter', the balance IS shown.  Did you ever check for compile errors? Your posted link does not compile because it is missing an 'EndIf'